# How to make a UILabel which adjusts it's text to the upper left?

Tags: iphone, uilabel

For some strange reason, in iPhone OS 3.0 this doesn't work: I made a big fullscreen UILabel with `numberOfLines = 0` and `baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustmentNone`.

It refuses to show the text in the upper left. It's always in the center of the bounding box, aligned to the left.

The documentation says:

> UIBaselineAdjustmentNone Adjust text
>   relative to the top-left corner of the
>   bounding box. This is the default
>   adjustment. Available in iPhone OS 2.0
>   and later.

Probably a framework bug? I started with shiny new labels to test it. Text is centered.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default implementation vertically centers text and does not honor the `contentMode` property.  Implement `drawTextInRect:` in a subclass.

```
@implementation TopLeftLabel

-(void) drawTextInRect:(CGRect)inFrame {
    CGRect      draw = [self textRectForBounds:inFrame limitedToNumberOfLines:[self numberOfLines]];

    draw.origin = CGPointZero;

    [super drawTextInRect:draw];
}

@end
```

The `baselineAdjustment` property is strictly for when the font size is being adjusted to fit the width.